# Native linking error on xamarin ios binding

Tags: c++, ios, xamarin, linker, xamarin.ios-binding

I am writing a wrapper that bind to an iOS SDK using the P/Invoke as Sharpie was not able to generate a compilable code for this SDK.

When compiling the iOS App with the wrapper project referenced I am having many linking issues such as this one :

> MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: std::locale::classic(). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
>   MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: std::__throw_bad_cast(). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
>   MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument(std::string const&). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (Please find the complete log on this [complete log file](https://15254b2dcaab7f5478ab-24461f391e20b7336331d5789078af53.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/xamarin.vanillaforums.com/FileUpload/2f/c613e9d593a67fa837609ace5c273a.doc).)

The extra mono touch argument passed from the iOS project are described below:

> -cxx -v -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lstdc++ -lresolv -liconv -lxml2 -lz -ObjC
>    -force_load ${ProjectDir}/Libs/libcrypto.a" -cxx -v -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lstdc++ -lresolv -liconv -lxml2 -lz -ObjC -force_load ${ProjectDir}/Libs/libssl.a" -cxx -v -gcc_flags "-lstdc++ -lresolv -liconv -lxml2 -lz -ObjC -L${ProjectDir} -framework Security -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreAudio -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -force_load ${ProjectDir}/Libs/libsipwrapper.a -dead_strip -all_load"

The SDK is composed of three libraries : libcrypto.a, libssl.a and libsipwrapper.a.

Following many articles/posts on the internet, it is recommended to add add the standard library such as -lstdc++, lz, and ObjC, but this not seems to work on my case.

I have also tried to create a Binding Project that includes the three libraries and the wrapper code, the content added to the linkwith files seems like that :

> [assembly: LinkWith ("libsipwrapper.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Arm64, Frameworks = "CoreVideo CoreMedia AVFoundation CFNetwork Accelerate AudioToolbox CoreAudio Foundation CoreGraphics UIKit", ForceLoad = false, SmartLink = true, IsCxx = true, LinkerFlags = "-lstdc++ -lresolv -liconv -lxml2 -lz -ObjC")]

The problem was not resolved and I continue to have the described linking errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days of wasted time, I finally got it, to be clear, it's not evident to guess the parameters to pass to touch, to link correctly a library built by a tier only by yourself. To simplify the task, I have compiled the demo app provided by the SDK provider and used Xcode to compile the demo and gets the parameters sent by Xcode to clang++. this helped me to figure out the parameters to send to monotouch:

> --compiler:clang++ -cxx -v -gcc_flags "-stdlib=libstdc++ -L${ProjectDir} -force_load ${ProjectDir}/Libs/libcrypto.a" -cxx -v -gcc_flags "-stdlib=libstdc++ -L${ProjectDir} -force_load ${ProjectDir}/Libs/libssl.a" -cxx -v -gcc_flags "-dead_strip -lresolv -liconv -stdlib=libstdc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreAudio -lz -lxml2 -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -L${ProjectDir} -force_load ${ProjectDir}/Libs/libsipwrapper.a"

Hope this will help other guys.

(Check the two points described by @NyxSway below are also very important)

Comment: I have the same situation. Could you please say me where did you find the place to see the compile parameters which sends by XCode to clang++?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more details of your project, have you checked:

1) have you checked if your .a file really have that symbol it's complaining about using terminal -> grep command, for all the architecture you are supporting: armv7/armv7s/arm64

2) in your C# code, did you use [DllImport ("__Internal")]  instead of your own library name?

Comment: At first, thanks for you answer, 1. Not checked yet if the .a file have that symbols for different supported architecture, I will check them now and feedback you. 2. Yes I am using [DllImport("__Internal")] instead of [DllImport("libsipwrapper")].